# Mapping a JSON const in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a bunch of configurations in a `const` in my React.js app and the JSON looks like this:

```
const original = [
  { 'id': '1', 'desc': 'AAA', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '2', 'desc': 'BBB', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '3', 'desc': 'CCC', 'isOK': false },
  ...
];
```

It contains a bunch of configurations that I'll likely put in a separate file somewhere, but for now I wanted to test it and thought that a `const` would be appropriate.

I'm attempting to use the [ReactiveSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactivesearch/) component and feed this to [`MultiDataList`'s `data` field](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/list-components/multidatalist.html) for which it needs to be transformed into:

```
[
  { label: '1', value: 'AAA' },
  { label: '2', value: 'BBB' },
  { value: '3', value: 'CCC' },
  ...
]
```

I had assumed that `original.map(e => { 'label': e.id, 'value': e.desc })` would do the trick but I get that 'Unexpected token' at the first colon. IntelliJ says 'Expression statement is not assignment or call'.

Mapping through the array with individual items works just fine, e.g. `original.map(e => e.id)`, so I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I've only started tinkering with JavaScript and React.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to implicitly return an object from an arrow function, you need to surround the `{` and `}` brackets in parentheses, else the interpreter doesn't know how to differentiate it from an ordinary function block that starts with `{`:

```js
const original = [
  { 'id': '1', 'desc': 'AAA', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '2', 'desc': 'BBB', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '3', 'desc': 'CCC', 'isOK': false },
];

console.log(
  original.map(e => ({ label: e.id, value: e.desc }))
);
```

Note that there's no need to put quotes around the object properties (which are assumed to be strings by default) - only string *values* need to be enclosed in string delimiters.

Another method, using destructuring:

```js
const original = [
  { 'id': '1', 'desc': 'AAA', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '2', 'desc': 'BBB', 'isOK': true },
  { 'id': '3', 'desc': 'CCC', 'isOK': false },
];

console.log(
  original.map(({ id, desc }) => ({ label: id, value: desc }))
  // or:
  // original.map(({ id: label, desc: value }) => ({ label, value }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you got it slightly wrong.

```
const original = [
 { 'id': '1', 'desc': 'AAA', 'isOK': true },
 { 'id': '2', 'desc': 'BBB', 'isOK': true },
 { 'id': '3', 'desc': 'CCC', 'isOK': false },
 ...
];
```

In the ES5 syntax it look's like this:

```
original.map(config=>({label:config.id,value:config.desc}))
```

Also notice the paranthesis around the returning object.It is necessary.

You can also do it like this.

```
original.map(function(config){
   return {
      label:config.id,
      value:config.desc
   }
})
```

Comment: Do the parentheses mean it's wrapped in a tuple?

Comment: @MaxPower writing like this .map(e=>e.id) and .map(e=>(e.id)) and .map(e=>{return e.id}) are all same.The paranthesis is required if there is no return statement.

Comment: @MaxPower here the parantheses are used to differentiate `{` as start of a function from start of an object.

Comment: The map functions expects to return an object inside it.Wrapping paranthesis in the ES5 is a cleaner way to achieve without that the whole object is like a function body without returning any thing.Kepp learning....